# ZipArchive is adding another ending to zip file

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

When there is only one file to add to the Zip file my code works perfectly fine but as soon as I add multiple files to the zip I get files like: Photos.zip.gefBCk !

Here is my code for creating a ZipArchive:

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
            if ($zip->open('/var/www/html/downloads/' . $user . '/photos.zip',  ZipArchive::CREATE))
            {
                if($handle = opendir('/var/www/html/downloads/' . $user . '/'))
                {
                    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle)))
                    {
                        if ($entry != "." && $entry != ".." && !is_dir('/var/www/html/downloads/' . $user . '/' . $entry))
                        {
                            if(strpos($entry, '.png') !== false)
                            {
                                $zip->addFile('/var/www/html/downloads/' . $user . '/' . $entry, basename('/var/www/html/downloads/' . $user . '/' . $entry));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    closedir($handle);
                }
                $zip->close();
```

Thank you for your time!